# axios-on-rails, how to request set of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, axios

I'm creating an app in Rails with a ReactJS front-end. In my front-end I'm using the axios-on-rails yarn package to make all my requests to my Rails api back-end.

Heres what I'm trying to do: for the main page of the site I want to implement an infinite scroll feature. For that to work well I need to be able to request small sets of records as the page continues to scroll. The only way I know how to pass records to my front-end is using:

```js
axios.get('/posts.json')
  .then((response) => {
    ...
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This returns ALL posts though, which eventually will be thousands. I don't want that happening. So how do I modify this request so that I only get the first 20 records or so?

**Answer Details**

Okay so I took a second look at pagination as @Gagan Gupta suggested and after a few hours got it to work. Heres what I did.

`yarn add react-infinite-scroll` to get the component needed.

For my feed component I did...

```js
import React from 'react';
import Post from './Post';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadPosts } from '../actions/posts';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';
import axios from 'axios-on-rails';

const node = document.getElementById('owc_feed_payload');
const numberOfPosts = JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('number_of_posts'));

class Feed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: props.posts,
      hasMoreItems: true,
      page: 1
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props !== prevProps) {
      this.setState({ posts: this.props.posts, hasMoreItems: this.props.hasMoreItems });
    }
  }

  loadMore = (page) => {
    axios.get('/posts.json', {
      params: { page: page }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.props.dispatch(loadPosts(response.data));
        this.setState({ hasMoreItems: this.state.posts.length < numberOfPosts ? false : true, page: this.state.page + 1 });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    let items = [];
    this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
      items.push(
        < ... key={index}>
          ...
        </...>
      );
    });

    return (
      <InfiniteScroll
        pageStart={0}
        loadMore={this.loadMore}
        hasMore={this.state.hasMoreItems}
        loader={<p>Loading...</p>}>
          { items }
      </InfiniteScroll>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    timestamp: state.timestampReducer,
    posts: state.postsReducer
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Feed);
```

I used redux to manage the state of my posts. Next I added `gem 'kaminari'` to my gem file and ran `bundle installed` then added this line to my controller's index action: `@posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc).page params[:page]` and this to my model: `paginates_per 5`.

Now it scrolls and loads as expected! Awesome.

Comment: you can use pagination?

Comment: As in use the [pagination gem](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#other-frameworklibrary-support) for rails? I'm not sure how I would make that work with my front-end.

Comment: for every request it will give you as many records as you want per call. For example if you want 10 records per call. You just have to add page parameter and increment after each call and it will get you different records.

Comment: @GaganGupta I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: Sure, do let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: @GaganGupta Took me a bit but I got it working! Thanks for the starting point and enjoy your checkmark! Edit: or I would give you a checkmark if you gave an answer.

Comment: sure thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to use pagination. 
Every request will be bring only a set of records you'll specify in the method.
you can perform using gems like [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate), [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) & this is the new gem called as [pagy](https://github.com/ddnexus/pagy) and they claim that it's faster than the other two.

Just increment the page parameter in the url after every request till the last page and you'll get the output you need.

I'm glad my opinion helped you :)

Change your JS code to this:

```
axios.post('/posts.json', {
  params: {
    page: page
  }
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    ...
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Enjoy the rest of your day/night, sir.

Comment: you too @GregoryJaros !

Comment: One more thing. I spoke a little too soon when I said it was working. So, as I scroll it loads more posts like I want but they are the same posts over and over. I guess that has to do with incrementing the page parameter in the url but I don't know how to format that in my `axios.get`. I tried something like this: `axios.get('posts?=' + page + '.json')` but that just gets me a bunch of html back.  Is this something I even do in my request or something I do in my routes or controller?

Comment: `posts?page=' + page + '.json'` try this?

Comment: share your controller method as well

Comment: That didn't work. My rails server does this: `Started GET "/posts?page=1.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-10 10:41:37 -0400
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"page"=>"1.json"}
` and I get a bunch of HTML. =/

Comment: sorry for late reply. try shifting your get request to post request and send page params in body of the post request instead of url.

Comment: Not a problem man. I'm just grateful you're sticking with me. I edited my post to give you more information. I'm not sure what you mean by "shifting [my] get request to post" so I tried doing it with `get` again.

Comment: try changing `axios.get` to `axios.post`

Comment: do you have a github repo?.. check my answer

Comment: I DID IT! All I had to do was add `.json` to the request url. What I have in my post above works. So basically it's `axios.get('/posts.json', { params: { page: page } }).then((response) => { ... }).catch(error => ...);}` Thanks for all your help man!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at console.log(response) after axios then method so you can see the array of objects returning from the server. After then you can set it with .length property of method like:

```
axios.get('/posts.json')
  .then((response) => {

    if(response.data.length > 20){
      console.log(response.data.slice(0,20))
      }
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: I thought about doing that. The thing is though is that the request is still for thousands of records. It doesn't seem like the optimal way to do it.